# Vertical floating divs - overflow to the right

Tags: html, css

The content div contains an X amount of divs inside of it, but what i would wand is that the divs inside the content div to *float(open for sugestions)* from top to bottom instead of left to right.
and when the divs in the content div reaches it max-height the divs inside the content div overflow to the right and start over from top to bottom (as shown in the example below), and so, stretch the content divs width to fit a new row.
I also would like to make it work in mobile browsers.

```
css---------------------------------------:
.content {
float: left;
min-width: 100px;
height: 95%;
}
.block {
float: left;
width: 100px; 
height: 100px;
}

html---------------------------------------:
<div class="content">
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
</div><!-- end content -->
```

My questions are: 
1: how can i let the divs(inside the content div) float from top to bottom.
2: when the content div reached the max-height how can i let the divs float next to eachother and start a new vertical row.

```
+ ==== content ==== +                                   + ==== content ====================== +
| +---------------+ |                                   | +---------------+ +---------------+ |
| |               | |                                   | |               | |               | |
| |     div 1     | |                                   | |     div 1     | |     div 4     | |
| |               | |                                   | |               | |               | |
| |               | |                                   | |               | |               | |                 
| |               | |                                   | |               | |               | |                 
| +---------------+ |                                   | +---------------+ +---------------+ |
| +---------------+ |                                   | +---------------+ +---------------+ |
| |               | |                                   | |               | |               | |                 
| |               | |                                   | |               | |               | |
| |     div 2     | |   when more then 3 divs vertacly  | |     div 2     | |     div 5     | |
| |               | |   i wand it to expand horizontaly | |               | |               | |
| |               | |                                   | |               | |               | |
| |               | |                                   | |               | |               | |
| +---------------+ |                                   | +---------------+ +---------------+ |
| +---------------+ |                                   | +---------------+                   |
| |               | |                                   | |               |                   |
| |               | |                                   | |               |                   |
| |     div 3     | |                                   | |     div 3     |                   |
| |               | |                                   | |               |                   |
| |               | |                                   | |               |                   |                 
| |               | |                                   | |               |                   |
| +---------------+ |                                   | +---------------+                   |
+ ================= +                                   + =================================== +
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so using `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column`

**Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hpy3vt1s/**

This demo is using the `<div id="container">` as indicator for available space, which is 100% of the view port height. You will have to set a `height` or `max-height` to controll the max items per row. When you'd set  `max-height: 330;` exactly 3 items would be in one row/column: [Here is a demo showing this](http://jsfiddle.net/hpy3vt1s/2/)

```
body
{
    margin:0;
}

#container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100vh;
}

#container .box
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: silver;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
   ....
</div>
```

Information on Browser-Support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox (IE10+)

Nice article on flexbox: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Yes that does the trick! thank you Nico O for the efford! i never heard of "Flexbox" i shal read the article of flexbox to undertand it better.
the only problem i have now is that if the container div has min-width 100px to it, it wil take up all the width it can get to fit the box divs. the box divs have a auto margin between the rows to fit the width of the container. i dont undertand that yet, but maby if i have read the article i can remove that auto margin and set it to 5px so the container div does not stretch the whole screen width.

thank you very much Nico O!